# How to use .htaccess to rewrite url nicely

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web

Hi I was wondering what I would write in my .htaccess to do the following.

I want:

```
profile.php?profile=X9H6W6
```

to redirect to:

```
/profile/X9H6W6/
```

Not too sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?profile=$1 [L,QSA]
```